# Laravel AJAX POST Request failing (500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I've been stuck with this for hours, checked dozens of examples / StackOverflow answers but I am still getting the same error.
It's my first time working with AJAX, but I have a solid amount of experience with Laravel.

The issue I'm getting is a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to send my AJAX request, the aim of which is to update a single row in my database.

I've read that the error is likely caused by the CSRF token not being validated / passed to the back-end, but despite changing my code I am still getting the same issue.

Here is my code:

```
view.blade.php
```

```js
<script>

  function likeCandidate(id){
    console.log("Calling like candidate function");
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/employer/likecandidate',
      data:{
        '_token' : $('[name="_token"]').val(),
        'cand' : id,
        'job' : {{$id}},
        },
           success:function(data) {
    }
  });
  }
</script>
```

```html
<!-- In the HTML I am including: -->
@csrf
```

And in my routes I have the post route:

```
  Route::post('/likecandidate', 'AjaxController@likeCandidate');
```

And finally in my controller I have the code:

```
public function likeCandidate(Request $request)
{

  $this->validate($request, [
    'cand'=>'required',
    'job'=>'required',
  ])

  // Find the application
  $application = Application::where('candidateId', $request->input('cand'))
                                 ->('jobId', $request->input('job'))
                                 ->first();

  // Update the candidate's status to liked.
  $application->status = "Liked";
  $application->save();

  // Return status message
  $msg = "Success";

  return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Didn't realise I should be checking storage/laravel.log until now! Just checked and found out it was a syntax error in my controller function... I assumed it wasn't making it as far as the controller. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake from me here, but I guess I've never used AJAX before so wasn't aware this was an issue. I'm leaving this answer here just in case someone makes the same mistake.

Check storage/laravel.log to find out the error message when trying to run the function. In my case I had a couple of syntax errors in my likeCandidate function, and this was causing a 500 Internal Server Error (I assumed that the 500 error meant it wasn't able to access the controller.)

Comment: The tip on" laravel.log" really helps me on debugging.